# Как убрать последний элемент при повторяющемся фоне если он обрезается?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть блок, в зависимости от действий пользователя у блока меняется высота, есть фоновая картинка у блока которая повторяется по вертикали. Нужно чтоб последний фон, если он не влазит просто не показывался.
Возможно ли это реализовать только при помощи CSS? Если да, то как?
Если нет, то возможны ли варианты на чистом JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если без скриптов, то CSS умеет заполнять фон картинками, подгоняя их размер или добавляя просвет между ними.

Если задать для [`background-repeat`](https://webref.ru/css/background-repeat) значение `round`, то фоновая картинка будет автоматически увеличиваться, чтобы поместилось целое число картинок.

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7G6Z.jpg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat round;
}
```

Если задать значение `space`, то размер фоновой картинки меняться не будет, но между её копиями возникнут просветы.

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7G6Z.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat space;
}
```

Эти варианты понимают [все современные браузеры](https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-repeat-round-space). IE — начиная с 11 версии.